# .NET End vs Form.Close() vs Application.Exit Cleaner way to close one's app

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, exit

sometimes, when I use Form.close() when debugging my program, although the form is closed, the application is still running. I noticed this behaviour when using the msgbox function.

I have no thread nor timer running, so what is the best way to close a .NET app? I am using VB.NET.

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The situation you describe is pretty fishy. Whenever you close your program's startup form, the entire application should quit automatically, including closing *all other* open forms. Make sure that you're closing the correct form, and you should not experience any problems.

The other possibility is that you've changed your project (using its Properties page) not to close until *all* open windows have been closed. In this mode, your application will not exit until the *last* remaining open form has been closed. If you've chosen this setting, you have to make sure that you call the `Close` method of *all* forms that you've shown during the course of application, not just the startup/main form.

The first setting is the default for a reason, and if you've changed it, you probably want to go fix it back.
It is by far the most intuitive model for normal applications, and it prevents exactly the situation you describe. For it to work properly, make sure that you have specified your *main* form as the "Startup form" (rather than a splash screen or log-in form).

The settings I'm talking about are highlighted here:

[image: Visual Studio Project Properties]

But primarily, note that **you should never have to call `Application.Exit` in a properly-designed application**. If you find yourself having to do this in order for your program to close completely, then you are doing something wrong. Doing it is not a bad practice in itself, as long as you have a good reason. The other two answers fail to explain that, and thus I feel are incomplete at best.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I didn't change the settings you are talking about, so I don't understand why when I close my form the whole app doesn't close; however, I will soon give further details about the app.

Answer (score 11):

In .Net 1.1 and earlier, [Application.Exit was not a wise](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224252(vs.71).aspx) choice and the MSDN docs specifically recommended against it because all message processing stopped immediately.

In later versions however, [calling Application.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224252(v=VS.100).aspx) will result in Form.Close being called on all open forms in the application, thus giving you a chance to clean up after yourself, or even cancel the operation all together.

Comment: Tanks for the explanation and the links

Comment: You forgot to mention that a properly-designed application should never find itself having to call `Application.Exit` in order to quit properly. Your answer is correct as far as it goes, but it doesn't go far enough.

Comment: @Cody, fair enough. I wasn't really trying to convince him of using one or the other. Merely presenting what will happen when Application.Exit is called. I agree that typically you will want to set your shutdown mode to close when the main form closes, but I can think of half a dozen scenarios where this is not the case. Saying that calling Application.Exit is indicative of a poorly designed application is simply wrong. It would only be poor design if you blindly chose to use one or the other without considering why ;)

Comment: Yeah, like I said, your answer isn't incorrect. But sometimes on Stack Overflow, you have to try and read people's minds. My reading of the question is that the asker wants to know why their application isn't closing the way they expected. Tossing in a call to `Application.Exit` will in fact fix that problem, and many people will stop there. (As probably happened here, seeing as your answer was accepted.) That's obviously not your fault, but it's something I try to keep in mind. Most people *do* blindly choose to use whatever "works" without considering why. Unfortunate, but real.

Comment: @Cody, it is worth noting though that Application.Exit and ShutdownMode == OnMainWindowClose are very different beasts. OnMainWindowClose will implicitly call Application.Shutdown, which ignores any attempt to cancel that event during any subsequent Form.Closing events. I think this is precisely why they default the ShutdownMode to OnLastWindowClose in WPF.

Comment: @Cody, to your other point... sadly you are very correct that most people will simply copy and paste answers directly into their code without any regard as to how or why it might work. Which is usually evidenced by the large number of "I tried this and it doesn't work" comments here on SO *sigh*

Comment: Actually, none of the answers were complete (regarding to the question), as I also talked about the "End" statement. This page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/0wt87xba%28v=VS.100%29.aspx
gave me further information about it.

Comment: But according to this page: 
" Because End terminates your application without attending to any resources that might be open, you should try to close down cleanly before using it. For example, if your application has any forms open, you should close them before control reaches the End statement.

You should use End sparingly, and only when you need to stop immediately. "

So I will simply avoid using the End statement in the future.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in a loop (Do While, For, ...) and you call `Me.Close()`, you should follow with an Exit command (Exit Do, ...) or a `Return()` to force the message processing to terminate properly. I caught programs hanging due to this.

Answer (score 1):

Just put "End" keyword in your code.

```
Sub Form_Load()
  Dim answer As MsgBoxResult
  answer = MsgBox("Do you want to quit now?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
  If answer = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
      MsgBox("Terminating program")
      End 
  End If 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`Application.Exit()` kills your application but there are some instances that it won't close the application.

`End` is better than `Application.Exit()`.

Comment: Never call End in a forms application.

Answer (score 0):

Form.Close() is use to close an instance of a Form with in .NET application it does not kill the entire application. Application.exit() kills your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer which helped me too