# VB.NET - Working with Multiple Forms

Tags: vb.net, forms, user-interface

I'm trying to make a login window and a main window. The problem is when I close the login form and show the main window, the whole program stops.

**The login form:**

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net

Public Class frmLogin

    Dim address As String = "http://puu.sh/jKJ**Zq/d613de****29.txt"
    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()

    Private Sub frmLogin_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'frmMain.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmLogin_Close(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
        frmMain.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If attemptLogin() Then
            MsgBox("Login Successful")
            Me.Close()
            'frmMain.Show()
        Else
            MsgBox("Username or password is incorrect")
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Function attemptLogin()
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(client.OpenRead(address))

        Dim line As String
        Dim username As String
        Dim password As String

        line = reader.ReadLine()

        Do While Not line Is Nothing

            username = line.Split(":")(0)
            password = line.Split(":")(1)

            If (username = TextBox1.Text And password = TextBox2.Text) Then
                Return True
            End If

            line = reader.ReadLine()

        Loop

        reader.Close()
        client.Dispose()

        Return False

    End Function

    Private Function Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(client.OpenRead(address))
        Dim line As String

        line = reader.ReadLine

        Do While Not line Is Nothing
            line = reader.ReadLine()
        Loop

        reader.Close()
        Dim writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(client.OpenRead(address))
        writer.Write(TextBox1.Text & ":" & TextBox2.Text)

        writer.Close()
        client.Dispose()

        Return False

    End Function

End Class
```

**The Main Window:**

```
Public Class frmMain

    Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'frmMain.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmMain_closed(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

    End Sub

End Class
```

I am fairly new to VB.NET so sorry about the lack of knowledge/ugly coding. I'm used to programming GUIs in Java.

Comment: Go to Project Properties and change the Shutdown Mode to "when last form closes"

Comment: Probably you could get an hint to your problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976380/net-end-vs-form-close-vs-application-exit-cleaner-way-to-close-ones-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your 'Shutdown mode' to 'When last form closes'.

You can find this setting by going to *My project* and then clicking on *Application* (the first tab).
You can then find the setting at the bottom.

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn't know I could do that. Another question, are both forms created at program start, or just the form which I select display when the program starts?

Comment: Just the form you've selected. But you can easily open the second form with frmSecond.ShowDialog() when the first form loaded.