# Should we stop program when the windows close?

Tags: vb.net

I added this code on my main form closed

```
Private Sub nicehashform_Closed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Closed
    End
End Sub
```

However it seems to be closing just fine even without it under debug mode. However, outside debug mode, the windows are closed all right but the process is still there.

I wonder what keeps the program running when all forms are already closed.

Comment: I must admit that i didn't even know the [`End` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/end-statement) (without any other keyword).

Comment: You should never use `End` statement - form(s) closing should be enough. Probably some of your forms don't close properly or you have created some other thread, not finished yet or you have some strange cyclic relations between public objects or similar. Check your objects disposing routines carefully.

Comment: End is absolutely not needed here. The [`ShutdownMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) defines when the application should stop running. (can be configured in `Application.xaml` or in `My Project`.

Comment: @Arvo: true, but doesn't explain this issue. As far as what i've read `End` is the ultimate hammer(which calls `Environment.Exit`). The process is killed and even finally statements won't run(if `End` is called within try-catch). Of course you should prefer other ways, especially to ensure that all resources are disposed properly. So why the process is still running? One thing that comes to my mind is, you don't have `UnmanagedCode` permission, so a `SecurityException` occured. Look at your windows event entries. Maybe the app is running on a network share.

Comment: Foreground threads keeps the process running until they're closed. Make sure all your threads stop themselves when your application is closing, alternatively set the [**`IsBackground` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground(v=vs.110).aspx) to `True` on each thread (only applicable on raw threads) to let the framework close them for you.

Comment: Do you have any parallel threads? If yes you might have to stop them before closing your application.

Comment: not that I know off. I will run this again under debug mode and close the window see if any code is running.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The `End` statement is a legacy statement since old Basic. I know it since GW-Basic era.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET End vs Form.Close() vs Application.Exit Cleaner way to close one's app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976380/net-end-vs-form-close-vs-application-exit-cleaner-way-to-close-ones-app)